# Why F11 don't step into the .NET Framework source code?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I followed the steps described [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/setup.html) but when I tried to step into sentences like `var c = new SqlConnection();` (pressing F11) I don't end inside the *SqlConnection* constructor source code. What I'm missing?

**EDIT:**

> [How does reference source relate to the Microsoft Symbol Server?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source.aspx)
>
> The Microsoft Symbol Server is a repository where all public PDBs
>   generated by most teams at Microsoft end up. However all PDBs that are
>   present here do not have any source information in them, which makes
>   them not very useful for stepping through sources. When you are trying
>   to debug .NET Framework source please ensure that you do not have the
>   Microsoft Symbol Server enabled. Doing so could result in the symbols
>   being loaded from the Microsoft Symbol Server and the source stepping
>   experience would not work in that case. You can disable Microsoft
>   Symbol Server lookup via Tools | Options | Debugging | Symbols. Ensure
>   that the checkbox in front of Microsoft Symbol Server is unchecked.

Comment: Perhaps you need to add a location for the source code.  IntelliJ does it automatically for Java code; don't know about Visual Studio.

Comment: In VS is like is described [Using .NET Reference Source for debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/02/24/a-new-look-for-net-reference-source.aspx), my problem is that it don't work, at least for me.

Comment: Deleted my answer below.  Misread the MSDN page while scanning for an answer.

Comment: Can you confirm that the pdbs are getting loaded into your symbols directory?

Comment: Thanks @SteveMitcham. How I can do that? I don't know either how *Validate that your Symbol path has no cached symbols.* as I read in the troubleshooting section of [the doc](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/).

Comment: Make sure that in Debugging->Symbols the Microsoft Symbol Servers option is checked and  fill in a directory in 'symbol cache directory...'.  Then click the 'Empty Symbol Cache' button.

Comment: @SteveMitcham Pls read my quote in the question about Microsoft Symbol Server and .NET source code debugging. Doing what you said not solved the problem. I really appreciate your effort Steve, thanks you.

Comment: @gsc-frank after clearing the symbol cache, when you start debugging VS should spend some time re-downloading symbols. Can you confirm that happens? Also that the symbol path you specified is repopulated.

Comment: @Basic That happened. At the end the problem was solved unselecting the *Microsoft Symbol Server* (as the doc said) BUT specifying a *Cache symbols directory*, a thing that the doc not said ;) Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the end the problem was solved unselecting the *Microsoft Symbol Server* (as the doc said) BUT specifying a *Cache symbols directory* in that same configuration dialog box, a thing that the doc not said ;)

Answer (score 1):

My problem was that I used Framework 4.5 instead of 4.5.1. Once I changed that, it still didn't run. In "Tools | Options | Debugging | Symbols", I had to execute "Empty Symbol Cache", after which I could singlestep into the Framework.